# Triangular faces when using bevel

Tags: faces, bevel, distort

I have this model:
[image]

When I apply Bevel, these triangular faces appear:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Activating Harden Normals fixed this issue.

Comment: Please put this solution as an Answer to mark this as solved. 
Thank you @JachymMichal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a shading issue.
Try these things in this order.

1. Enable *Clamp Overlap*
2. Enable *Harden normals*
3. Enable Mesh > *Autosmooth*

[image]